# Golang program reversing with Radare2

Tags: radare2

I'm trying to understand how to reverse golang programs with radare2. In order to practice, i create a minimal program in Go:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

In the resulting assembly code below, i found the main function (main.main) but i can't figure how to display the string passed in argument to Println.

```
;-- sym.go.main.main:
mov rcx, qword fs:[0xfffffffffffffff8]
cmp rsp, qword [rcx + 0x10]
jbe 0x485097
sub rsp, 0x48
mov qword [var_40h], rbp
lea rbp, [var_40h]
xorps xmm0, xmm0
movups xmmword [var_30h], xmm0
lea rax, [0x004958e0]
mov qword [var_30h], rax
lea rax, obj.main.statictmp_0 ; 0x4c8490
mov qword [var_38h], rax
lea rax, [var_30h]
mov qword [rsp], rax
mov qword [var_8h], 1
mov qword [var_10h], 1
call sym.fmt.Println
mov rbp, qword [var_40h]
add rsp, 0x48
ret
call sym.runtime.morestack_noctxt
jmp sym.main.main
```

Any tips ? Im new in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

> For future people: Now days IDA has native support for golang, and free for x64 versions, check out the freeware version.([here](https://hex-rays.com/blog/announcing-version-7-6-for-ida-freeware/)) (15/06/2021)

Here is the set of tools that I use in my GO analysis and reverse engineering, I'm sure it will be very useful for you to use it until it is simplified, but you still need a knowledge of IA-32/64, [GO-RE KIT](https://go-re.tk/), another tip I have to give you is "Keep an eye on the debbug sections", GO developers often forget the debbug section and this can make your life easier when analyzing, here is a list of useful materials cured by me that will help you:

1. [Reversing Linux Malware GO](http://repository.root-me.org/Reverse%20Engineering/EN%20-%20Golang%20Reverse%20-%20Zaytsev.pdf)
2. [Reversing GO binaries like a pro](https://rednaga.io/2016/09/21/reversing_go_binaries_like_a_pro/)
3. [Defcon - Reversing golang](https://www.slideshare.net/DefconRussia/reversing-golang-66820671)
4. [GoUtils](https://gitlab.com/zaytsevgu/GoUtils2.0/)

Comment: Thanks for the resources ! But why do i need to use specialized tools ? Is this impossible with just radare2 ?

Comment: It is not impossible, on the contrary it is excellent to use tools like radare2, we will take into account the difference between languages for example when we compile in C we have some more code represented by the functions in which we already know, for example a printf, already in GO for being a new language some tools do not have this support or if it is still very initial and for beginners using a specific tool will help to better understand the source decompiled, and consequently understand faster and analyze in different and simplified ways.

Comment: After some time doing the reverse engineering for specific tools as mentioned by me you will have a new vision and consequently you will be able to better differentiate the machine code in tools like radare2 or other excellent tools that help our life.